# preg_match regex to make http:// and https:// optional

Tags: php, regex

I want to validate URL in PHP but the function should accept the URL even if http:// or https:// not present in the input.

Following URL's should be acceptable:

```
http://example.com
http://www.example.com
https://example.com
https://www.example.com
www.example.com
example.com
```

It should not accept ftp protocol, IP address, Port, URL path, query, or fragment.

Comment: What did you tried ?

Comment: If you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do, but it's almost certain to lead to disaster.  What about all the new TLDs?  For example, `realtor`.  That's one word, no dots, and is perfectly valid.  How do you plan to handle situations like that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?\w+\.[a-z]{2,6}(\/)?$
```

You should add `?` after `http(s)` and `www` in order to make them optional.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/8So1CF/1/

Comment: Thanks it worked well but one thing I missed in acceptable example list is trailing slash. e.g. http://example.com/ So I edited your regex by adding (\/)? at last:  ^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?\w+\.[a-z]{2,6}(\/)?$

Comment: @MahadevMajaladar That's right! Adding `(\/)?` at the end is the correct way to account for the trailing slash. I edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: What change should I make If I want to accept subdomains also?

Comment: replace `www` with `\w+`

Comment: Thanks. @Ibrahim